# jQuery UI Dialog Position is Incorrect When Opened In $(document).ready Function

Tags: jquery, position, modal-dialog, document-ready

My jQuery UI modal dialog shows up center screen when displayed from say a button click event, however, if I open it during document.ready, in the loginDialog() method below, it is displayed at the bottom of the scrollable window.

I suspect the issue is related to the fact that I am loading a number of images in document.ready prior to the dialog open call. The viewable part of the screen is disabled but the dialog is at the bottom of the scroll window. Interesting to note that the dialog position option

```
position: 'top',
```

does not seem to work during document.ready either.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        serverGetMenu();
        getPhotos();

        $("#loginDialog").dialog({
            .............
        });

        if (isLoginRequest()) {
            loginDialog();
        }
    });
```

How can I get the dialog to be placed correctly during or shortly after document.ready?

Comment: Can't you just put the `dialog()` in the bottom of your `getPhotos()` function?

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved : Turns out that my jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css was not correct.

My original ThemeRoller 'build' did not include the Dialog widget so I created a new build to include the Dialog widget. I then just replaced my existing jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js with the new one but I didn't also update the jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css file.

Due to my lack of experience with jQuery UI I didn't realize that, while my Dialog worked, it's styling was just a bit off from what it should be, I had to add a bit of styling to correct the minor issues. The correct jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css also resolved the styling 'issues' that I had to fix.

I find it quite interesting that the missing Dialog style classes didn't really manifest that big of an 'issue' until I tried to show my Dialog in document.ready. I never knew styling could cause such strange issues and be so hard to track down.